# php web based app or desktop app to managing columns and insert rows to them, then managing rows, search in them, display them and filter them!

Tags: php, cms

I'm looking for a php web based app or desktop app to managing columns and insert rows to them, then managing rows, search in rows, display them and filter them!
Is any application for this work exists?
I want to make phonebook using that and any many other things.
Thanks.

Comment: For what database (eg. MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, …)? And while you ask for an app, your last sentence rather sounds like you look for an API (to access from your phonebook app)?

Comment: It does not matter which database. but I prefer MySQL. No, I'm not looking for API. I want to make colums, it columns can be like phonebook columns (like First name, Last name, phone number, adress, ...). Then I wan't insert row to this table.

Comment: Would something like [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) fit your purpose? As the name suggests, it's an administration frontend for MySQL. You can use it to create/modify/delete databases, tables etc. and of course also insert/update/delete data and show contents of tables, incl. filtering etc.

Comment: No، Its personalization is low and its facilities are high. I want to use it like cms, in administration you can add rows. then visitors can visit table only!